# Connect error with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: mysql, php

When i browse my website, evrything works fine. The website connects with database and displays results. However, i get this error whenever it encounters `mysql_resl_escape_string`:

> mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in......

Please note that the website runs fine as soon as i remove the mysql_real_escape_string code from every page. But, this is not justified. What is the fix for this thing?

Comment: how do you use mysql_real_escape_string() ?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() must be after mysql_connect() just check this

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() requires a connection to have been established to a MySQL database server... have you already connected at this point or not?

Comment: also what PHP version are you using? that function is not present in very old versions and will be removed in 5.5

Comment: is your site on local or another server?

Comment: @Naryl: No, not removed in 5.5 ;) However, you should not use them any longer for new code, that's correct.

Comment: @user2003663: Show your code, normally that function will pick the last connection. Probably connecting to the database did not work in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `mysql_real_escape_string` to work, you first have to connect to MySQL via `mysql_connect`

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the default mysql database connection is not properly configured within your `php.ini`.

You will likely use `mysql_real_escape_string` without having connected to the database first, which is the case that PHP will try to connect to the database with the default configuration from `php.ini`.

In your case these defaults didn't work well, that's all.

Change the configuration and the error goes away - or - provide a valid mysql database connection as parameter to the [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) function call.

*Additional Note:* Drop the `mysql_*` functions to access your mysql database if you're writing new code. Choose `Mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You you passing in the connection variable returned from mysql_connect as the second parameter?

On a side note, you should really be moving over to using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it escapes strings automatically if you use its prepare function.

Answer (score -1):

You are using this function wrong way.
Instead of processing **only string values** right before placing them in the query, you are processing **all user input** values somewhere at the top of your code.
It will lead you to sql injection